# <cite> html tag better practices

Tags: html

Its a good practice use cite html tag like that?

what w3schools says: The  tag defines the title of a work (e.g. a book, a song, a movie, a TV show, a painting, a sculpture, etc.).

```
<footer>
  <cite>
    Copyright &copy; Trade, Inc.
    <br>All rights reserved.
  </cite>
</footer>
```

It's right use like that?

Comment: Is `Copyright &copy; Trade, Inc. All rights reserved.` The title of your work?

Comment: w3schools is not an official source and has, historically, had non-conforming inaccurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5 as you quote from w3school, cite should be used for the title of a work.

So the "correct" (in fact, more elegant) use would be :

```
<footer>
  <cite>
  This Amazing Website
  </cite>
  <small> Copyright &copy; Trade, Inc. </small>
  <br>All rights reserved.
</footer>
```

Comment: not sure why my answer is downvoted, and the other one upvoted while we're saying the exact same thing.

Comment: You don't cite yourself in your own website in much the same that you would never document your own research paper as a citation in itself.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have written and read numerous research papers using self-citation, so although I understand your point, your comparison is highly subjective.

Comment: why you used <small> ?

Comment: @Raduken Because this is most appropriate for an indication that is not part of the actual content of the website.

Comment: @Raduken, [because it's appropriate](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-small-element).

Comment: great thanks @zoubida I am not understand why people down voted this you are right. i will give you a plus.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the *actual <cite>HTML5</cite> specification*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-cite-element):

> The `cite` element represents a reference to a creative work. It must include the title of the work or the name of the author(person, people or organization) or an URL reference, which may be in an abbreviated form as per the conventions used for the addition of citation metadata.

So your example is invalid, as "Copyright…all rights reserved." is not a reference to a creative work.